# Ice in kiddush wine/grape juice to cool it. What halachic issues would be involved and what are the views?

Tags: grapes-wine, kiddush

On a hot shabbos, I would like to put some ice into my kiddush wine/grape juice to cool it. What halachic issues would be involved and what are the views?

1] Does the solid ice contribute to the required volume of the wine/ice mixture?  I saw in Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchoso that the ice does not contribute the required volume (can't find it now).

2] Is there a problem with the dilution of the wine or grape juice? My friends tell me that our wines can be diluted up to one-third with water. But I have seen that there are [wines that will not tolerate any dilution](https://dinonline.org/2019/09/20/ice-in-kiddush-cup/).

Comment: Why not make wine or grape juice ice cubes and avoid any safek at all?

Comment: Excellent but does it solve the volume issue?

Comment: If you have a large kiddush cup (average size) you're getting several revit of wine anyway

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, assuming you already have the appropriate volume for kiddush, its not a problem. In fact, its actually brought down as an solution in order to make your cup  if you have the volume without having enough to fill the cup to the brim.
One of the sources that I can find for this right now is the Mishna Berura 182:32

Regarding your second question, in general your friends are right that it can be diluted up to a third, but you can run into issues with grape juice according to some, and even more so with light grape juice.

Comment: "In fact, its actually brought down as an eitzah in order to make your kos malei if you have the shiur without having enough to fill the cos to the brim." Ice specifically or any solid item, eg. stones?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Jay and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note in particular the focus on English. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thanks @JayJay and welcome. Your answer would be much improved if you quoted sources to support your statements.